# How to get json file

Tags: json, web-services, web, dictionary, web-deployment

How can I get json file for the point at the map from this web site http://espace-sfr.sfr.fr/espace-sfr/recherche#Paris

I need to get the points from map to display them at my own map. So if there is any json file with all that points and coordinates?

Comment: the link is taking a long time to open...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the following URL

```
http://espace-sfr.sfr.fr/espace-sfr/recherche
```

With params

- **inputSearch:** The city name.
- **rayon:** Ratio in Km. (possible values 5, 25, 50 and 100)
- **latitude and logitude:** I am not completely sure but seems to be the coordinates from the searched city.

An example URL

```
http://espace-sfr.sfr.fr/espace-sfr/recherche?search=&inputSearch=Paris&rayon=5&latitude=48.856614&longitude=2.3522219000000177
```

Comment: but how can I get all the points?